# Search for particular string in <td> of html code and if present print next <td> vaule using JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

```
 I have html code like below

<html>
<body>

<div id="1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>   

        <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>Fail</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>   

        <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>Success</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="3">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>789</td>
        </tr>   

        <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>Fail</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="4">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>135</td>
        </tr>   

        <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>Success</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to parse this HTML code. I need to iterate through all div tags present and Search for "Search" in the td's in every div iteratively. If present get its 2nd adjacend td value i.e., Fail / Success. if If is "Fail" then I need to again search for "ID" and if present I need to print its 2nd adjacent div value i.e., 123 and 789 in this case.

Pseudo code might look like below

```
if(code contains "Status")
{
    1. Get its 2nd td value i.e., Fail/Success

   if(td value is "Fail")
  {
    1. Search for "ID"
    if("ID" present)
    {
        Print the number/2nd adjacent <td> value    
    }
  }
}
```

I had tried this in javascript something like below

```
var t0=$(this).find('tr:has(td:contains("Test Status"))');
        if (t0.length) 
        {
            var str0 =t0.text().trim();
            str0 = /:(.+)/.exec(str0)[1];

            if(str0 == "FAIL")
            {

                var t1=$(this).find('tr:has(td:contains("Test ID"))');
                if (t1.length) 
                {
                    str =t1.text().trim();
                    str = /:(.+)/.exec(str)[1];
                    testIDArray.push(str);
                    // alert(str);
                } 
           }
```

But I need to do it in java using jsoup. I tried somethinng like below

```
String htmlString = fileContent;
            Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
            Elements elements = document.body().select("div"); for (Element element : elements) { String link = element.select("td:contains(Test Status)").attr("<tr>");

                 if(link != null || !(link.isEmpty())) 
                 {
                        System.out.println(link);
                        System.out.println("=========================");
                 }
            }
```

Kindly help me with this. I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java Streams to solve this:

```
List<String> failedIds = document.body().select("div table").stream()
        .map(e -> e.select("tr"))
        .filter(trs -> "FAIL".equalsIgnoreCase(trs.last().select("td").last().text()))
        .map(trs -> trs.first().select("td").last().text())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result will be:

```
[123, 789]
```

First you select `div table` to get all the elements. Then you select all `tr`s and filter those which have Status `Fail` (`trs -> trs.first().select("td").last().text()`). At the end you map the ID (`trs -> trs.first().select("td").last().text()`).

To print the ids instead of creating a List you can use `.forEach()`:

```
document.body().select("div table").stream()
        .map(e -> e.select("tr"))
        .filter(trs -> "FAIL".equalsIgnoreCase(trs.last().select("td").last().text()))
        .map(trs -> trs.first().select("td").last().text())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Alternatively you can use this (without Streams):

```
for (Element e : document.body().select("div table")) {
    Elements trs = e.select("tr");
    if ("FAIL".equalsIgnoreCase(trs.last().select("td").last().text())) {
        String id = trs.first().select("td").last().text();
        System.out.println(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Samuel Philipp Thanks for your reply. I tried your code using Java streams, it printed empty list. second snippet didnt print anything.

Comment: Hi @Samuel Philipp I'm loading html content from a html file and stored in a variable. Please see the pseudo code in my question. I have updated it. I tried replacing "Status with "Fail" none is working. Kindly help

Comment: List<String> failedIds = document.body().select("div table").stream()
              .map(e -> e.select("tr"))
              .filter(trs -> "Test Status".equalsIgnoreCase(trs.last().select("td").last().text()))
              .map(trs -> trs.first().select("td").last().text())
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
      
      System.out.println(failedIds);    Prints []

Comment: You should use `Fail` as this is the value in the last `td`. Please also verify the html string you are parsing. I tested it yesterday and it worked perfectly with the HTML you shared.

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks @Samuel Philipp